# How do I multiply lists together using a function?

Tags: python, list, multiplication

how do I multiply lists together in python using a function? This is what I have:

```
    list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    def list_multiplication(list, value):
         mylist = []
         for item in list:
              for place in value:
               mylist.append(item*value)
    return mylist
```

So I want to use this to multiply list*list (1*1, 2*2, 3*3, 4*4)

So the output would be 1, 4, 9, and 16. How would I do this in python where the 2nd list could be anything?
Thanks

Comment: The problem with the original code is that it iterates the inner list (value) *once* for *each iteration* of the outer list (list). While there are many approaches below, the fundamental key to this is "iterating two lists in step".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My favorite way is mapping the `mul` operator over the two lists:

```
from operator import mul

mul(2, 5)
#>>> 10

mul(3, 6)
#>>> 18

map(mul, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
#>>> <map object at 0x7fc424916f50>
```

`map`, at least in Python 3, returns a generator. Hence if you want a list you should cast it to one:

```
list(map(mul, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]))
#>>> [6, 14, 24, 36, 50]
```

But by then it might make more sense to use a list comprehension over the `zip`'d lists.

```
[a*b for a, b in zip([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10])]
#>>> [6, 14, 24, 36, 50]
```

To explain the last one, `zip([a,b,c], [x,y,z])` gives (a generator that generates) `[(a,x),(b,y),(c,z)]`.

The `for a, b in` "unpacks" each `(m,n)` pair into the variables `a` and `b`, and `a*b` multiplies them.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
>>> t = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> [i**2 for i in t]
[1, 4, 9, 16]
```

Note that `1*1, 2*2, etc` is the same as squaring the number.

---

If you need to multiply two lists, consider [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> L1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> L2 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> [i*j for i, j in zip(L1, L2)]
[1, 4, 9, 16]
```

Comment: I know, but how would I do it with another list? So the list I provided above multiplied by another list? Say I do the list above times the list of list2 = [2,5,6,3]

Answer (score 0):

If you have two lists `A` and `B` of the same length, easiest is to `zip` them:

```
>>> A = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> B = [5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> [a*b for a, b in zip(A, B)]
[5, 12, 21, 32]
```

Take a look at `zip` on its own to understand how that works:

```
>>> zip(A, B)
[(1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7), (4, 8)]
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do it without zip? That works good, but I'm just curious. Thanks

Comment: Sure, there are countless ways to do it ;-)  For example,

`[A[i]*B[i] for i in range(len(A))]`

Comment: @user2817437  Did you not see my post? I covered a way 25 minutes before you asked. Also see [`izip`'s equivalent implementation from the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) for a way to do this manually without indexing.

Comment: @TimPeters can you elaborate a little more on that other example? How would it fit into a function and for loop?

Comment: @user2817437, sorry, I can't guess what you're asking for.  How about editing your question, to summarize **exactly** what you're looking for:  input, output, and what you've tried that still doesn't get you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

`zip()` would do:

```
[a*b for a,b in zip(lista,listb)]
```

Answer (score 0):

`zip` is probably the way to go, as suggested by the other answers. That said, here's an alternative beginner approach.

```
# create data
size = 20
a = [i+1 for i in range(size)]
b = [val*2 for val in a]

a
>> [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20] 
b
>> [ 2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 26 28 30 32 34 36 38 40] 

def multiply_list_elems(list_one, list_two):
    """ non-efficient method """
    res = [] # initialize empty list to append results
    if len(a) == len(b): # check that both lists have same number of elems (and idxs)
        print("\n list one: \n", list_one, "\n list two: \n", list_two, "\n")
        for idx in range(len(a)): # for each chronological element of a
            res.append(a[idx] * b[idx]) # multiply the ith a and ith b for all i
    return res

def efficient_multiplier(list_one, list_two):
    """ efficient method """
    return [a[idx] * b[idx] for idx in range(len(a)) if len(a) == len(b)]

print(multiply_list_elems(a, b))
print(efficient_multiplier(a, b))
```

both give:

```
>> [2, 8, 18, 32, 50, 72, 98, 128, 162, 200, 242, 288, 338, 392, 450, 512, 578, 648, 722, 800]
```

Yet another approach is using numpy, [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22240280/least-squares-fit-to-a-straight-line-python-code/22241415#22241415).

Answer (score 0):

Use numpy for this.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> list = [1,2,3,4]
>>> np.multiply(list, list)
array([ 1,  4,  9, 16])
```

If you prefer python lists:

```
>>> np.multiply(list, list).tolist()
[1, 4, 9, 16]
```

additionally, this also works for element-wise multiplication with a scalar.

```
>>> np.multiply(list, 2)
array([2, 4, 6, 8])
```