# Least-Squares Fit to a Straight Line python code

Tags: python, plot

I have a scatter plot composed of X and Y coordinates. I want to use the Least-Squares Fit to a Straight Line to obtain the line of best fit.

The Least-Squares Fit to a Straight Line refers to: If(x_1,y_1),....(x_n,y_n) are measured pairs of data, then the best straight line is y = A + Bx.

Here is my code in python:

```
 # number of points is 50
 A = (sum(x**2)*sum(y) - sum(x)*sum(x*y)) / (50*sum(x**2) - (sum(x))**2)
 B = (50*sum(x*y) - sum(x)*sum(y)) / (50*sum(x**2) - (sum(x))**2)
 print (A,B)
```

Does this look correct, I'm having issues printing A and B. Thank you!

Comment: this might be a good start for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19017301/how-do-i-multiply-lists-together-using-a-function

Comment: @george I've looked into the zip function before but never really undertood what it does. The examples in that link do a good job showing what zip does and I believe it will help.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you have two datasets `x` and `y` where you want to perform a least square fit.

You don't have to write the algorithm yourself, `curve_fit` from `scipy.optimize` should do what you want, try:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def f(x, A, B): # this is your 'straight line' y=f(x)
    return A*x + B

popt, pcov = curve_fit(f, x, y) # your data x, y to fit
```

where `popt[0]`, `popt[1]` would be the slope and intercept of the straight line.

For more details and examples, see:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html#scipy.optimize.curve_fit

Answer (score 43):

Simplest if you just want a line is `scipy.stats.linregress`:

```
from scipy import stats
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x,y)
```

[Link to docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html)

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution using **only numpy** would be this one:

```
import numpy as np

slope, intercept = np.polyfit(X, Y, deg=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to multiply two lists `x` and `y` (or by itself) but it is not defined in Python. You either need to write your own function to do the list element-by-element multiplication or use `numpy.multiply`. For example, if you want to do elemet-wise multiplication of x and y,

```
import numpy as np
xy = np.multiply(x,y)
```