# Multiplying corresponding elements from 2 lists in Python

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I was wondering if anyone could help explain how to code the following task in Python using stdin

---

**Programming challenge description:**
You have 2 lists of positive integers. Write a program which multiplies corresponding elements in these lists.

**Input:**
Your program should read lines from standard input. Each line contains two space-delimited lists. The lists are separated with a pipe char (|). Both lists have the same length, in range [1, 10]. Each element in the lists is a number in range [0, 99].

**Output:**
Print the multiplied list.

**Test Input:**
9 0 6 | 15 14 9

**Expected Output:**
135 0 54

Comment: What code have _you_ written to solve this and where exactly are you facing issues?

Comment: Please see [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I multiply lists together using a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19017301/how-do-i-multiply-lists-together-using-a-function)

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
input_string = input().strip()
list1 = map(int, input_string.split("|")[0].split())
list2 = map(int, input_string.split("|")[1].split())
result = " ".join([str(n1*n2) for n1, n2 in zip(list1, list2)])
```

OR,

```
input_string = input().strip()
list1 = input_string.split("|")[0].split()
list2 = input_string.split("|")[1].split()
result = " ".join([str(int(n1)*int(n2)) for n1, n2 in zip(list1, list2)])
```

OR,

```
import operator

input_string = input().strip()
list1 = map(int, input_string.split("|")[0].split())
list2 = map(int, input_string.split("|")[1].split())
result = " ".join(map(str, map(operator.mul, list1, list2)))
```

**OUTPUT of `print(result)`:**

```
135 0 54
```

Comment: You can also replace `zip` with `map`: `" ".join(map(str, map(operator.mul, list1, list2)))`.

Comment: @chepner Yep, That will also do. I'll add that to answer.

Comment: Why not just do `str_1, str_2 = input_string.split("|")`, and then `map()` those?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are asking for help and not just a solution, here are some useful functions that should give you some inspiration:)

```
input("give me some") #reads a string from stdin.
"abcabcbbbc".split("c") #splits the string on "c" and returns a list. 
int("123") #converts the string to an int object.
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#Input comma seperated values
a = input("Values of first list: ")
a = a.split(",")
b = input("Valies of second list: ")
b = b.split(",")
c = []
counter = 0
for each in a:
    c.append(int(each) * int(b[counter]))
    counter += 1
```