# How to multiply each element of two lists in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, return, iteration

So I got it work from an answer to a similar question but not the result I wanted.

```
list1 = [1,1,1] 
list2 = [5,10,15]

result = [[m*n for m in list1]for n in list2]
print(result)     # [[5, 5, 5], [10, 10, 10], [15, 15, 15]]

newresult = result[0]
print(newresult)  #  [5, 5, 5]
```

Is there a way I can get the single list `[5,10,15]` as the original output?

Comment: Whats causing the nested list.... can you see why it's happening?

Comment: from [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19017344/7505395) of the dupe:  `[a*b for a, b in zip([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10])]`  => `[6, 14, 24, 36, 50]`